# How can a static import be asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, import

I am using webpack and typescript and I am trying to import all objects from a library and for some reason it returns a promise. I would like to know how is this possible ?

```
import * as lib from 'pdfjs-lib';
console.log(app);
```

The result of this is:

```
[object Promise]
```

I've tried to figure this out using both the webpack doc and the typescript doc but I can't seem to understand how this is possible...

The requesting file is a ts file, while the requested file is a js module. The requested lib is an alias to this one: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/pdf.js (as can be seen in the webpack.config.js)

My webpack config:

```
"use strict";

import '@ungap/global-this';
import * as  path from "path";
import webpack from "webpack";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
import CopyPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import * as es6Promise from "es6-promise";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import NodePolyfillPlugin from 'node-polyfill-webpack-plugin';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default (config) => {
  const env = config.NODE_ENV;
  config.stats = {
    errorDetails: true, // --display-error-details
  }
  const files = [
    { from: "pdf.js/external", to: 'external' }
  ];
  if (env === 'development') {
    files.push({ from: "examples", to: "examples" });
  }
  console.log(`Launching webpack with env: ${env}`);
  return {
    mode: env,
    stats: {
      errorDetails: true, // --display-error-details
    },
    entry: {
      index: "./src/main.ts"
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'PDF Viewer'
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "css/app.css"
      }),

      new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'ts-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.hbs$/,
          use: ["handlebars-loader"]
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: true, sourceMap: true } },
            { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.properties$/,
          loader: "properties-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|cur)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[path][name].[ext]",
                publicPath: '../'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
      fallback: {
        fs: false
      },
      alias: {
        "pdfjs": path.resolve(__dirname, 'pdf.js/src'),
        "pdfjs-lib": path.resolve(__dirname, 'pdf.js/src/pdf'),
        "display-fetch_stream": path.resolve(__dirname, 'pdf.js/src/display/fetch_stream'),
        "display-network": path.resolve(__dirname, 'pdf.js/src/display/network'),
        "display-node_stream": path.resolve(__dirname, 'pdf.js/src/display/node_stream'),
        "display-node_utils": path.resolve(__dirname, 'pdf.js/src/display/node_utils'),
        "web-l10n_utils": path.resolve(__dirname, 'pdf.js/web/l10n_utils')
      }
    },
    output: {
      filename: "js/app.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      publicPath: '/',
      libraryTarget: "umd"
    },
    devServer: {
      static:  {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
      },
      port: 3999
    },
    experiments: {
      topLevelAwait: true
    }
  }
};
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "es7"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "pdfjs": ["./pdf.js/src"],
      "pdfjs-lib": ["./pdf.js/src/pdf"],
      "display-fetch_stream": ["./pdf.js/src/display/fetch_stream"],
      "display-network": ["./pdf.js/src/display/network"],
      "display-node_stream": ["./pdf.js/src/display/node_stream"],
      "display-node_utils": ["./pdf.js/src/display/node_utils"],
      "web-l10n_utils": ["./pdf.js/web/l10n_utils"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's not the import itself is async. It looks like the imported code when it runs returns a promise.

Comment: That's normally not possible though because `import *` is used which should always return an object!

Comment: can you include your code with the exported value from your `app.js`?

Comment: I've updated the question to include a link to the `app.js` file

Comment: I've updated the question in order to reflect the advance in my research, it looks like it comes from the lib, when I comment the import of it in the imported file (app.js) it no longer returns a promise.